# Validating Import CSV at Laravel

Tags: validation, laravel, csv, import

I want to import csv file with matlab/Excel at laravel 5.2,

the price should be integer, but when someone input price as string, i need to validate it.

This is my code:

```
Excel::filter( 'chunk' )->load( $path . $filename )->chunk( 1000, function( $results ) {
    foreach ( $results as $import_data ) {
        $validation = Validator::make( $import_data->toArray(), [
            'code' => 'required|alpha',
            'name' => 'alpha',
            'number' => 'alpha',
            'price' => 'numeric',
            'pages' => 'numeric',
            'delivery_id' => 'numeric'
        ] );
        if( $validation->fails() ) {
            return back();
        }

        if( $binder = Binder::where( 'code', $import_data->code )->first() ) {
            $binder->update( [
                'price' => $import_data->price,
                'pages' => $import_data->pages
            ] );
        } else {
            Binder::create( [
                'code' => $import_data->code,
                'name' => $import_data->name,
                'number' => $import_data->number,
                'price' => $import_data->price,
                'pages' => $import_data->pages,
                'delivery_id' => $import_data->delivery_id
            ] );
        }
    }
});
```

After import csv, my return back() is not working at all, the controller still doing the foreach, how to enable my validation?

Answer (score 0):

You're returning from the `chunk()` method, and then it goes on to call the next iteration of the same `chunk()` method, and so on. I would suggest wrapping the entire thing in a try-catch-block and throwing an exception instead.

Edit: like this:

```
try {
    Excel::filter( 'chunk' )->load( $path . $filename )->chunk( 1000, function( $results ) {
        foreach ( $results as $import_data ) {
            // ...
            if( $validation->fails() ) {
                throw new Exception();
            }
            // ...
        }
    )};
} catch (Exception $e) {
    return back();
}
```

Comment: so i must use another chunk? yes i'm using try catch but the try catch not get the exception and i dont get the error cause.

Comment: No, the point is that you should NOT use more chunks. That problem is that it keeps going to the next chunk. I'll add what I mean to my post.